# tinycarousel scrolling doesn't work in a default android browser

Tags: android, jquery

I implemented tinycarousel for my little project and it works almost in all browsers, but scrolling doesn't work in a default android browser and I dunno how to debug it or fix, could anyone help me, please. Maybe anyone have the same issue?

Here is a simple code, which I use for this carousel:

```
$('#videoResume .videoResumeHolder').tinycarousel({interval: false, pager: true});
```